# How to use environment variable in import syntax?

Tags: angular, typescript, environment-variables

I am using angular v5. I want to do something like

```
import { OwnedSetABI } from 
`../constant/${environment.envName}/OwnedSetContractABI`;
```

I have OwnedSetContractABI file in different folder and want to use then according to environment. for example for dev env the path of OwnedSetABI would be '../constant/dev/OwnedSetContractABI', for production env the path of OwnedSetABI would be '../constant/production/OwnedSetContractABI'. But ES6 not allowd to use variable in import syntax. How I can achieve this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you can define multiple configurations inside your angular.json

```
     "production": {
     "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ]
     },
     "dev": {
         "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
            }
          ]

     }
```

and in each environment file you can import a specific OwnedSetABI from different directories
**environment.prod.ts**

```
export * from './prod/OwnedSetContractABI';
```

so you have just import that way

```
import {environment} from '../environments/environment';
```

and run build and serve for the wanted configuration dev or prod

```
ng build --env=production
```

or

```
ng serve --env=production
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `angular.json` and ctrl + f for "fileReplacements" and there you should see the answer you look for.

In short, you tell angular what to replace `environment.ts` with, depending on environment.

Any env-dependant variables put them in those environment files with the same variable name, and they would automatically be replaced on serve or build.. and then just import those in `environment.ts` (the one that is bound to be replaced)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by replacing `import` statement with `require` statement.
Try replacing

```
import { OwnedSetABI } from 
`../constant/${environment.envName}/OwnedSetContractABI`;
```

with

```
const OwnedSetABI = require(`../constant/${environment.envName}/OwnedSetContractABI`);
```

Thanks.